# How get the instance of the added days of DateTimeFormatInfo.FirstDayOfWeek?

Tags: c#, .net

Here is my simplified code:

```
DateTimeFormatInfo dfi = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo;

var firstReference = dfi.FirstDayOfWeek; // Currently, this could be Monday, Saturday, or Sunday.
var secondReference = dfi.FirstDayOfWeek.AddDays(3); // For this one, it should be something like 3 days after the dynamic value of FirstDayOfWeek.
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work like so. So, the question: is there any way to get the instance of the 3 days added `dfi.FirstDayOfWeek` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DayOfWeek` is an `Enum`, so you could just cast it to `int`, add days and cast back, something like:

```
var secondReference = (DayOfWeek)(((int)dfi.FirstDayOfWeek+3)%7);
```

You need `mod` to avoid having DayofWeek greater than 7.

Comment: if 2(!!!) downvoters could explaing what is wrong whith this answer, i would correct it. I don't see any issues on answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
DateTimeFormatInfo dfi = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo;

var firstReference = dfi.FirstDayOfWeek;
var secondReference = (DayOfWeek)(((int)firstReference + 3) % 7);
```

`DayOfWeek` is Enum so addition works fine on it.

Used Mod in case where + 3 exceeds limits of `DayOfWeek` (Saturday in your case).

[image]

Comment: You should use the modulus probably, otherwise 6+3 = 9

Comment: @xanatos: Thanks. Updated my answer.

Comment: @downvoter: Working Proof attached. Still care to explain, what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you can iterate days on dayofweek..

```
        DateTimeFormatInfo dfi = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo;
        List<DayOfWeek> daylist = new List<DayOfWeek>();
        int i = (int)dfi.FirstDayOfWeek;
        int addDay = 3;
        while (i <= ((int)dfi.FirstDayOfWeek + addDay) % 7)
        {
            daylist.Add((DayOfWeek)i);
            i++;
        }
```